# Modulus of random variable X is a random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

So I need to proof, that modulus of random variable X is a random variable again. I've got this done:
$$
\{\omega: |X(\omega)|\leqslant a\} = \begin{cases}
\varnothing,& a<0\\
\{\omega:-a\leqslant X(\omega)\leqslant a\},& a\geqslant 0.
\end{cases}
$$

But is it enough to say, that both sides belong to $F$? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. You should rely on picture for your mathematical expressions. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to help you with mathematical expressions.

Comment: You should've edited your question rather than providing an answer. Anyways ... it is correct except that, depending on the level at which the proof is required, you may need to provide more detail. For example, usually you assume sets such as $\{\omega:X(\omega)\le a\}$ belong to $F$, but can you assume the same for the sets such as $\{\omega:X(\omega)<a\}$ ($<$ replacing $\le$), or do you need to prove that?

Comment: I can use all previously proofed theorems and axioms, so I can replace < with  ≤ anytime. Thanks.